# Firefox location autocomplete without "Down" key (then enter)

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, speed

Here is the situation :

I type for instance "f" :

Then I should press the "Down" :

And finally press "Enter" to go to the website.

Instead, in Chrome, I have just to type "f" :

[image: Chromium]

Then Enter and it go to the website.

How could I skip the "Down" key step?

(I very often use the location bar this way, and with a netbook it's even annonying)

Comment: If I were a troll I would say you answered your own question: use Chrome.

Comment: Interestingly, I've seen this very feature receive considerable hate in Internet Explorer.

Comment: So, it's impossible to do that with Fiefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Enter Selects](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enter-selects/) extension to open the first result without having to use the down arrow or mouse. This extension does not require a restart of the browser.

Description of the extension:

> Press [Enter] in the AwesomeBar to select the first result, which will be automatically highlighted. This saves you from pressing [Down] or [Tab] before pressing [Enter] to select the first result.

Comment: It appears this extension is no longer available. Is there an alternative with the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Add Facebook to bookmarks; right-click the bookmark, click *Properties*, then enter `f` to the *Keyword* box.

Comment: And I should do that for every website I use ?

Comment: That's obviously not an ideal solution.